# Solve for the $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus

Solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ using chain rule if $$y= (u-4)^\frac{3}{2} \ \text{and} \ u=x^2+4$$

$$y=f(u), u=g(x)$$

I did get the derivative of y and the derivative of u, and then tried to multiply it. But i can't get the answer. Did I do the right thing?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the chain rule for: $y=f(g(x))$ 
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(\frac{3}{2}(u-4)^{1/2})\cdot(2x)$ 
Now, substitute u:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(\frac{3}{2}(x^2+4-4)^{1/2})\cdot(2x) = 3x(x^2)^{1/2}=3x^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$y= (u-4)^\frac{3}{2} \ \text{and} \ u=x^2+4$$

$$ \frac{dy}{du} = \frac{3}{2}(u-4)^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$ \frac{du}{dx} = 2x$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{dy}{du}\times\frac{du}{dx}$$

$$\frac{3}{2}(u-4)^\frac{1}{2} \times 2x $$

$$ 3x(x^2 +4-4)^\frac{1}{2}= 3x(x^2)^\frac{1}{2} = 3x^2$$

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved much easier.

$u=x^2+4$ and $y=(u-4)^{\frac{3}{2}}$. Therefore $y=x^3$ and $y'=3x^2$.

The derivative of $u=x^2+4$ is $u'=2x$.